# Pauli Decomposition

Tags: synthetic-aperture-radar

I would like to apply a Pauli Decomposition to my Dual-Pol SAR Data (HH; VV). As a result, I need the complex values from Pauli Basis HH+VV and HH-VV and I will not use it for a RGB picture generation. I know that the R, (G), B bands produced by the following intensities: R = 0.5*|Shh - Svv|²; B = 0.5*|Shh + Svv|²
My question is now how can I convert the intensities R and B to their complex forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your HH and VV data are "detected" amplitudes/intensities rather than SLC data (single look complex). In this case, you can use them directly and compute R = HH-VV and B = HH+VV. You could convert them back to complex numbers, but that would be meaningless without the phase information. Note that this is not truly a Pauli decomposition in the absence of the HV data.

EDIT, in light of OP comment:

If the data are truly SLC complex data, then you evaluate them as you wrote. In numpy this would be `0.5*numpy.abs(HH+VV)**2`, or using no temporary arrays:

```
HH += VV
del VV
numpy.abs(HH, out=HH)
HH **= 2
HH *= 0.5
```

where HH and VV are the original complex values. The output is a real number, so you can save HH.real to a Float32 file for further analysis.

Comment: Hello Benjamin, thank you for your reply. I have 2 TanDEM-X SLCs in a bistatic acquisition mode.